# How can I set field properties when an object is being created in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have a model like so:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title_max_length = models.IntegerField(default=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=self.title_max_length)
```

Basically, the user will set the title_max_length, and using that, we will set the title field max_length when an object is created.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, since `max_length` is something *static*, it is the maximum length of the *column*, and the column definition is for all records the same. You can however make a validator (for example in `.save()` or `.clean()`) that checks if what you do is valid. But this can - by some ORM calls - get circumvented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_length` is a "static" column property. A column has a maximum length, *not* the `title` column of a specific record.

Therefore you can not set the `max_length` based on properties (that relate to the record, or change based on time, etc.). Changing the `max_length` normally requires a database migration, since most databases need to know the maximum length.

You can however *validate* that the `title` does *not* exceed the given maximum. For example by overwriting the [**`Model.clean(..)` method**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Article(models.Model):
    title_max_length = models.IntegerField(default=255)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=self.title_max_length)

    def clean(self):
        if len(self.title) > self.title_max_length:
            raise ValidationError('Length of the title exceed maximum length')
        super(Article, self).clean()
```

(normally the `.clean(..)` is *not* called for a model save, only by forms, etc.).

Then it will raise an error in case somebody creates, or edits an `Article` in a `ModelForm` that way.

But regardless there are still ways to circumvent the check. This will also happen if we override the `.save(..)` function (although then it is enforced also on the model layer, but the Django ORM allows ways to circumvent the `.save(..)`).